# How to include css file in php?

Tags: html, css

I am using php file and want to include CSS file into PHP, I have included but its not working properly.

The file that I am executing is in this directory:

```
http://host.com/at_t/application/modules/employees/view/employee_detail_view.php?id=4
```

I want to include CSS file that exist in following directory

```
http://host.com/at_t/public/style/style.css
```

I have used code to include in PHP:

```
<link href="public/css/style.css" rel='stylesheet'/>
```

This code is not working. Please guide me what to do?

Comment: Does it work if you use `/at_t/public/style/style.css` or the complete address `http://host.com/at_t/public/style/style.css` with the code you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Here You Only Write Following Code.

```
<link href="/css/style.css" rel='stylesheet'>
```

Comment: No this is not working.If i write click and open source code then click over the css file path then it moves to this path and file not found appears http://host.com/at_t/application/modules/employees/view/public/css/style.css

Answer (score 0):

Put the following css inside of your existing html head tag. Like this. Then put css tags in php this:

```
<?php //code
 ?>php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
     <link href="/css/style.css" rel='stylesheet'>


   </head>
   <body>
        <?php
          echo "<div class='red'>I'm red</div>";
        ?>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Your CSS file

```
.red {
    font-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you didnt put the right path to your css file?

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://host.com/at_t/public/style/style.css" rel='stylesheet'/>
</head>
<body>

...

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) First thing you have typos in your code.

According to your question css file is in style folder(http://host.com/at_t/public/**style**/style.css) but you are adding wrong path in link href tag (< link href="public/**css**/style.css").

2) Second,

Your employee_detail_view.php file present in view folder(http://host.com/at_t/application/modules/employees/**view**/employee_detail_view.php?id=4) So if you give link href as (< link href="public/**css**/style.css") then also it can't find the css file because it search only in ***view*** folder and its sub folder for css file. So use complete address in your link href tag as follows.

< link href="http://host.com/at_t/public/style/style.css">

It may work.